# Corollary of the inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let  $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$  and $ f:U\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ injective and class $C^{1}$ such that $\det f'(x)\not=0$ for all $x \in U$. Show that $f(U)$ is open and  $f^{-1}:f(U)\to U$ is differentiable.

Furthermore,show that $f(V)$ is open for all $V\subset U$ open.

My attempt:

We will show that $f(U)$ is open, this is for each $x \in U$ there exists $B_ \epsilon (x) \subset f(U)$.

Then we aply the inverse function theorem to $f$ and $x$, this is possible because $\det f'(x)\not=0$, therefore there exist a neighborhood $V$ of x and $W$ of $f(x)$ such that $V=f(W)$, but we know that V is open, then we have that $\forall \epsilon>0 \;\;\;\; B_ \epsilon (x) \subset f(W) \subset f(U)$.

Now the differenciability follows from the inverse function theorem, and for the last part we aplly the same proof but to $f|_{V}$ since $\det f'|_{V}=\det f'(x)$.

My question is, am I right?,if not Can you help me to fix my proof please?

Thanks a lot in advance :).

Comment: You're sure right! Although local inverses are _local_ in general, once the mapping is globally injective _the local inverses are the localizations of the global inverse_. And then: a mapping is open (maps open sets to open sets) if and only if it is _locally open_. This topological aspect is the essential thing here.

Comment: Thnks a lot for your verification :) but I don't know topology yet :)

Comment: Well, but you have supplied the arguments behind, in fact.

Comment: ufff thanks a lot, :) I thought there were some things mising :)

Comment: But change $\forall\epsilon$ into _exists_ $\epsilon$. And also write: $\det(f'|V)=(\det f')|V$. I guess that $f'$ stands for jacobian of $f$.