# (Proof-verification) Corollary of inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\U}{\mathscr{U}}$$\newcommand{\V}{\mathscr{V}}$I have at least one question about my "proof" (see below); I forgot the second question:

**1.** Is the assumption of injectivity of $F$ necessary? I feel like it should be necessary to prevent differentiable covering space projections from being a counterexample, e.g. $F: \mathbb{R} \to S^1, F: \theta \mapsto (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Still it is not clear to me if the assumption is playing a crucial role in my proof or not or if I am still overlooking some aspect of it.

> Let $F: \U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an injective, smooth map with $\U$ open, such that $dF(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in \U$. Then there exists a smooth inverse $F^{-1}: F(\U) \to \U$, such that $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are diffeomorphisms between the sets $\U$ and $F(\U)$.
>
> **Proof:** Obviously for all $y \in F(\U)$ one has that there exists an $x \in U$ such that $y=F(x)$, i.e. clearly $F$ is surjective when its codomain is restricted to its range. Moreover, since $F$ is by assumption injective, $F$ is a bijection between $\U$ and $F(\U)$, and thus there exists a well-defined inverse function $F^{-1}:F(\U) \to \U$ -- all that remains to show is that $F^{-1}$ is smooth.
>
> We can apply the Inverse Function Theorem to get smooth local inverses in a neighborhood around each point of $x \in \U$. Let $\U_x$ denote the neighborhood of $x\in \U$ identified by the Inverse Function Theorem, $y:=F(x)$, $\V_y := F(\U_x)$, and define $G_y: \V_y \to \U_x$ to be the smooth local inverse which exists by the Inverse Function Theorem.
>
> Now define the function $G: F(\U) \to \U$ by stating that for each $y_0 \in F(\U)$, define $G(y_0)$ to be the value $G_y(y_0)$ for any $y$ such that $y_0 \in \V_y$. In particular $G(y_0)=G_{y_0}(y_0)$. We now need to show that $G$ is well-defined. Given that, $y_0 \in \V_{y_1}$, $y_0 \in \V_{y_2}$, define $x_0 = F^{-1}(y_0)$. Then by the Inverse Function Theorem, $G_{y_1}(y_0)=x_0=G_{y_2}(y_0)$, so not only have we shown that $G$ is well-defined, we have also shown that $G \equiv F^{-1}$ (i.e. that $G$ is identically equal to $F^{-1}$).
>
> Since $F^{-1}$ is smooth in a neighborhood of $y$ for all $y \in F(\U)$ (because the Inverse Function Theorem guarantees us that $F^{-1}=G=G_y$ is smooth on $V_y \ni y$) $F^{-1}$ is smooth. $\square$

Example application: let $F: (0,\infty)\times(0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(t,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : t \ge 0 \}$ be defined by $$F(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta). $$ Then because $F$ is injective and the determinant of its Jacobian ($=r$) vanishes nowhere on its domain, it is a diffeomorphism between $(0,\infty)\times(0,2\pi)$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(t,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : t \ge 0 \}$.

Related questions: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601567/inverse-function-theorem-and-injectivity), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166462/corollary-of-the-inverse-function-theorem).